# How do I prevent my Mac laptop from quitting applications trying to logout?

Tags: macos, user-account

If I leave my computer alone for some 1-2 hours, I don't know exactly how long, it tries to logout. But I have terminal programs running (CLI tools fetching data from FTP, or doing processing of some kind, etc.), so the computer never fully logs out. I don't want it to logout though, I want it to stay logged in. It's also quitting the browser and my text editor, which I don't want it to do.

What settings do I change? In System Preferences, I clicked "Start after: Never". I put Energy Saver to never sleep with or without battery. But I don't know what else to change to get it to not log out.

Maybe this helps:

[image]

Comment: It is not default behavior that the machine tries to log you out after a specified amount of time. It doesn't have to do with sleep mode either, as that doesn't log you out. I feel there's valuable information still missing from this question. Could you elaborate on what kind of computer you have (very specific) as well as whether this is a computer managed by your school, employer or similar?

Comment: It is a rose gold Macbook air a newer one from less than a year ago. It is not managed by anyone but me, it is my personal computer. How do I turn it off?

Comment: There's no normal setting that logs you off your computer after 1-2 hours. You must have setup something non-standard. Do you have any ideas as to what you could have installed?

Comment: @jksoegaard I don't know, I posted a screenshot of what my terminal says when it is tried to logout, but I don't know what I could have installed. Does [this](https://pdf.wondershare.com/macos-10-14/fix-macos-10-14-keeps-logging-you-out.html) have any relation?

Comment: It sound [like this is your issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/378499/119271)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it was because this:

[image]

I must have enabled that at some point, or I don't know what.

Comment: That explains it :-) - And yes, you must have enabled that.